# Composer failing with Signal 9

Tags: php, macos, composer-php, php-8

I'm puzzled about this Composer failure.  Can anyone help?  The only things I've seen about "signal 9" have to do with resource limitations, which I do not have.  It looks like a require() is failing?

I have a new M1-based macbook air, running PHP `8.0.0` and have Composer (v2.0.8) installed, both using `homebrew`.  I'm trying to create a new Cakephp project.

I have git installed and running.

When I run:
`composer -vvv create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app projectname`

Composer fails with a Symfony runtime exception `signal 9` - as below:

```
composer -vvv create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app projectname

Reading ./composer.json (/Users/xxxxxxx/Dropbox/Development/git/sites/composer.json)
Loading config file ./composer.json (/Users/xxxxxxx/Dropbox/Development/git/sites/composer.json)
Checked CA file /opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem: valid
Executing command (/Users/xxxxxx/Dropbox/Development/git/sites): git branch -a --no-color --no-abbrev -v

                                                          
  [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The process has been signaled with signal "9".          
                                                          

Exception trace:
 () at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:366
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->wait() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:198
 Symfony\Component\Process\Process->run() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php:125
 Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor->doExecute() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/ProcessExecutor.php:65
 Composer\Util\ProcessExecutor->execute() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionGuesser.php:122
 Composer\Package\Version\VersionGuesser->guessGitVersion() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionGuesser.php:71
 Composer\Package\Version\VersionGuesser->guessVersion() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/src/Composer/Package/Loader/RootPackageLoader.php:81
 Composer\Package\Loader\RootPackageLoader->load() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php:368
 Composer\Factory->createComposer() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/src/Composer/Factory.php:595
 Composer\Factory::create() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:409
 Composer\Console\Application->getComposer() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:527
 Composer\Console\Application->getPluginCommands() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:187
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:122
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer/bin/composer:63
 require() at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/composer/2.0.8/bin/composer:24
```

Comment: Signal 9 is a kill signal. Something is killing the composer process. An antivirus perhaps?

Comment: Would also suggest to just open a bug report, or see if a bug report exists. You're running on hardware that's not been tested a lot. Information about failures is helpful to get it in better shape. Also `*.0.0` versions of PHP tend to be a bit more shaky. You might want to keep that up to date until this stabilizes more

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved.  I used Homebrew to reinstall git.  Once I did that, composer worked.  What tipped me off was running "brew update" and getting:

*Error: Failure while executing; `git config --replace-all homebrew.analyticsmessage true` was terminated by uncaught signal KILL.*

I figured git was broken somehow (Odd, since I've been using it.) So I reinstalled it.